# Are all 'prospects' always 'potential' by their nature?

Tags: synonyms, pleonasms

When using the word 'prospect' is it ok to combine it with the word 'potential' or is it unnecessary, since all the 'prospects' are indeed always 'potential'?

Can / should we say 'potential prospects' or simply 'prospects' is sufficient and have the same meaning?

Comment: Hello, soocki. These Google Ngram results show that 'potential prospects' isn't used at all often. What do dictionaries say about the meaning of 'prospects': don't they, as you imply, indicate that potentiality is already implied?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring this out, hence the question. Mind you I am not a native English speaker so the exact nuances of the language are somewhat unfamiliar and unclear. I am trying to figure out if all the 'prospects' are always potential or it can be assumed that some 'prospects' can be taken for granted, which would justify the usage of the word 'potential' in this context.

Comment: I think it depends on context. For example, in a corporation I worked for, a 'prospect' was someone you were in contact with that might generate a sale and a 'potential prospect' was someone who might become a prospect (but who you hadn't yet contacted).

Comment: The 'prospects' I am referring to are the expected outcomes of a particular project I hope to engage in.

Comment: @Killing Time Even my wife, who predictably hates my (thankfully not me) foisting the nuances of the English language on her far too frequently, laughed at this unforeseen (to business virgins) complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prospect that is potential is *potentially* [pleonastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm).

That is, it is a fine distinction that works if in context there are potential prospects and actual prospects, but outside of any context, all prospects are potential.

Is the idea of 'potential' necessarily part of 'prospect'? No, but it does invoke some quizzical 'Isn't that already potential?'.

If you look at definitions of 'prospect' (where definitions aren't authorities, but are well-studied attempts at capturing meaning in other words), they all mention something having to do with future events. And the future is, implicatively, all potential.

If your boss makes a distinction between potential sales prospects and actual ones, then it's not redundant. Otherwise, 'potential' will be taken as already understood in 'prospect'.

Answer (score 1):

While a prospect is a potential customer/client/buyer, a potential prospect is not yet at that stage:

> There are two types of prospects; those that have an identified a need and are therefore potential buyers, and [*potential prospects*](https://books.google.de/books?id=TmJcDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT173&lpg=PT173&dq=%22potential+prospects%22&source=bl&ots=rSYBtjU7Ad&sig=ACfU3U3SI3XOjneNpQU54OBcKfAuAef0JQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1sMam9bviAhWSUlAKHfz1DFA4HhDoATAAegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%22potential%20prospects%22&f=false) who may or may not be viable. Usually you start with potential prospects, prospects that use or could use your product or service, but have no identified need. Through a series of questions, you narrow down the field to true prospects, a percentage you will convert to buyers. — James J. Kolins, *Salesman to Superstar: Out Sell, Out Close, Out Earn Your Competition!*, 2013.

Potential prospects can also be called *leads*:

> Qualifying is the process that allows you to find out whether a lead is actually a prospect. A prospect is someone who has the potential to become a customer. Leads, on the other hand, are just [*potential prospects*](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/what-is-qualifying-2917378). If you don't qualify a lead, you may be wasting your time with someone who literally can't buy from you. — Wendy Connock,   “What Is Qualifying?” BalanceCareers.com, 2 Dec. 2018.

Using the term *potential prospects* is thus not a tautology and makes a valid distinction between potential and actual prospects who may buy/contract for your goods or services.